# Error trying to copy files with find and cpio

Tags: linux, bash, find, cpio

I have a bash script that I use to periodically make a backup of proofs (PDFs & JPGs) from a server I work on. I put together the script a couple of years ago and it used to work however the script is now resulting in `0 block error`. I've been using cpio rather than copy so that the directory structure of the server is copied at the same time.

Here's the script

```
find "$JOB_DIR" -type f  \( -iname '*.pdf' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.jpeg' -or -iname '*.jpg' -or -iname '*.gif' -or -iname '*.psd' \) -path '*/D_Jpgs Pdfs to Client/*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file cpio -pvda file "$PROOF_DEST"

exit 0
```

And here's the error.

```
0 blocks
0 blocks
```

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find "$JOB_DIR" -type f  \( -iname '*.pdf' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.jpeg' -or -iname '*.jpg' -or -iname '*.gif' -or -iname '*.psd' \) -path '*/D_Jpgs Pdfs to Client/*' | cpio -pvda "$PROOF_DEST"
```

Simplified one liner that results in no errors.